# What are the UX Patterns for complimentary roles in a mobile app?

Tags: navigation, information-architecture, bottom-navigation

Consider an application where there are two parties with different roles that co-operate with each other. For example, rider and driver  in a ride sharing scenario, or a  client and a coach in sports scenario. I can see two options.

- **App per role** Publish two separate apps to the app stores (rider app, and a driver app)
- **Single app** Publish a single app to the app store that then runs in a mode based on the users profile. For example it can be rider mode or driver mode.

In the case of single app, what is a common UX pattern for handling switching between the roles, for example I might be a driver who sometimes wants to be a rider. What are some UX patterns for switching roles. I am making the assumption that the bottom tap bar in the mobile app will be full for each role  so I need a  different way to switch roles.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Gmail account switching patterns can be helpful. Have a visual cue in which profile the user is active. To avoid this problem in Gmail, I kept two distinct profile pictures manually.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend single App per role. We can see this in ride hailing apps like Uber and Grab. You can also find separate apps used in e-commerce apps.

I also see some benifits in terms of

1. app performance - too many users riders and drivers in your case could congest the server
2. download size - separate apps will be smaller in size and faster to download

Comment: At this point the app is just an idea. It's not practical to release two separate apps, which is why I am looking for patterns for a single app.